# libOSMesa.so is missing during Mesa installation

Tags: ubuntu, rendering, mesa, paraview, off-screen

I am trying to setup a Virtual Box for doing off-screen rendering with ParaView. I have Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit Server installed in the box. For setting up ParaView and Mesa I have followed the instructions the links below:

http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Users_Guide/Parallel_Rendering#Offscreen_Software_Rendering_via_OSMesa

http://paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/ParaView_And_Mesa_3D

Installation of Mesa completes fine without and errors or warnings but when I try to build ParaView and try to configure it for off-screen rendering, it gives an error in the middle of the "make" complaining about missing "libOSMesa.so". I searched the whole machine but that file is not there. It seems like it didn't get installed.

Am I supposed to install a library before building Mesa? How can I get that "libOSMesa.so" installed. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

you need install `libosmesa6-dev` package.